# Convert List<String> to string C# - asp.net - sql server -

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am new to this and I am asking for help to convert a string type data, I made an sql connection where I returned a name, address and phone number found in another table

[`List string eTelefono`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UVEp.png)
 [`while _Reader.Read`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNAOq.png)
[Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Ud6.png)

(If you see something in spanish is beacause im from Uruguay)
This the error 
[`error System.String to System.Collections.Generic.List 1 System.String`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TxWB.png)

Does anyone know how to convert `List <string>` to `string`?

Thanks!
If you need more captures just ask

Comment: Actually, pictures of code are frowned upon here. Please post the actual code in the body of your question.

Comment: oh i apologize

Part of The code:
 string eNombre, eDireccion;
            List<string> eTelefono;

 try
            {
                _Conexion.Open();
                _Reader = _Comando.ExecuteReader();

                while (_Reader.Read())
                {
                    eNombre = (string)_Reader["nombreE"];
                    eDireccion = (string)_Reader["direccion"];
                    eTelefono = (List<string>)_Reader["telefono"];

                    e = new EntidadPublica(eNombre, eDireccion,eTelefono);
                    _ListaEntidad.Add(e);

Comment: What value is in the `telefono` column? Is it a single telephone number? It looks like you're reading a `string` and then trying to cast it to a `List<string>`

Comment: Is a varchar(9)

Comment: Ah yes , is exactly that , the telephone column from the database is a varchar(9) and the builder from class is a List<string>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're reading in a single string when you do: `_Reader["telefono"]`, but you're trying to cast that to a `List<string>`.

Instead, you can just take that single string and add it as a single item to a list:

```
eTelefono = new List<string> { (string) _Reader["telefono"] };
```

The other option, of course, would be to define the `eTelefono` field as a `string` instead of a `List<string>`, since there's only one value associated with a record in the database anyway.

Comment: I have new errors : The best overloaded method 'System.Collections.Generic.List <string> .Add (string)' of the collection initializer has some invalid arguments

Comment: and cannot be converted from 'object' to 'string'.

Comment: was missing the `(string)` cast - updated the answer

Comment: It worked! But it doesn't show phone on the grid, show this: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: Why are you using a `List<string>` for a single `string`?

Comment: An immage : https://imgur.com/HWKPaeZ

Comment: I know! But my institute forces me to use it for my project, it would be very easy if I only used string and not list <string>